# Cannot cast IdentityUser instance to the instance of the class that inherits IdentityUser

Tags: c#, entity-framework, inheritance, asp.net-identity

I implemented .Net Identity in my application, and I have a class called Person that inherits IdentityUser. Here is my Person class:

```
public class Person : IdentityUser
{
    [Required]
    [StringLength(50, ErrorMessage = "First name cannot be longer than 50 characters.")]
    public string FirstName { get; set; }

    [Required]
    [StringLength(150, ErrorMessage = "Last name cannot be longer than 150 characters.")]
    public string LastName { get; set; }
}
```

Here is the code that I tried to bind the existing users (Person that inherits IdentityUser)

```
protected void Page_Load(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        var userStore = new UserStore<IdentityUser>(new gEchoLuDBContext());
        var userManager = new UserManager<IdentityUser>(userStore);

        List<Person> users = new List<Person>();
        users = (List<Person>)(from u in userManager.Users
                               select u);
        fw_CreateUser.DataSource = users;
        fw_CreateUser.DataBind();

    }
```

However I get an error for the LinQ statement line, it does not allow the casting from IdentityUser to Person:

> Unable to cast object of type 'System.Data.Entity.Infrastructure.DbQuery`1[Microsoft.AspNet.Identity.EntityFramework.IdentityUser]' to type 'System.Collections.Generic.List`1[gEchoLu.Model.Person]'.

Isn't this weird?

Comment: Every `Person` is an `IdentityUser`, but not every `IdentityUser` is a `Person`.

Comment: there may be also missing a `.ToList()` to the end of the query, but the remark of dasblinkenlight stays.